# Python OpenCV cv2.imshow() not working in windows

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to load a sample image using python 3.6 OpenCV. I do not know why my image is not loaded when I run my program. This is my code:

```
import cv2
import time

test1=cv2.imread("C:/Users/JP/Desktop/JP Files/Python/Python
Programs/FaceRecog/data/test1.jpg")
cv2.imshow("Test", test1)
```

I already changed the slash to C:\UsersJP\Desktop\JP Files\Python\Python
Programs\FaceRecog\data\test1.jpg but still no luck.

Comment: What does it mean that it is not loaded ?, the image is not displayed, the window is not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try by adding `cv2.waitkey(0)` at the end of the program. Hope it will work!!!!